# r data import custom markup

Tags: xml, r, markup, data-import

I am trying to import a series of custom data files into R.

The files are organized into blocks, which are marked by XML-like markup tags. I understand that these files are not true XML-files and they contain no definition of markup language.

Each block may be a single line or a tab delimited matrix.  Comments tend to be marked by a %

The files are ~10K lines long and I need around 2700 lines from each of them, so I would rather want to avoid loops. Also the file length and number of needed lines varies by somewhat unpredictable factors.

I have tried a number of the methods from the XML package, but always get bunch of errors such as "StartTag: invalid element name" and "Premature end of data in tag MERGED-PUPIL-DATA line 5443".

Do you have any ideas?  Are there any methods that accept custom markup tags?

A typical file may look something like this (dots indicate stuff I cut out)

```
<SESSION>
<VERSION>
2
<\VERSION>
<DATE>
2014-01-20 14:29:43
<\DATE>
<SUBJECT-ID>
SUB001
<\SUBJECT-ID>
<NOTE>
red300os
<\NOTE>
<MIN-MAX-PLOT>
0.100000 8707.554688
<\MIN-MAX-PLOT>
<STIMULUS-DEFINED>
redOS300
Default Human Relative Spectral Sensitivity
1   0
1   10.000000   20.000000   60.000000   1   3   2.000000    -100.000000 0.000000    0.000000    1
<\STIMULUS-DEFINED>
.
.
.
.
.
.
<MERGED-PUPIL-DATA>
% time is in sec; diameter is in mm; loci is in pixel; color code -> 100 = unknown, 0 = white, 1 = red, 2 = green, 3 = blue; intensity is in Lux or W/m2
% real time logical time    R. valid    R. diameter R. x loci    R. y loci  L. valid    L. diameter L. x loci    L. y loci  R. led color     R. led intensity   L. led color    L. led intensity
2703
-0.049000   -0.049000   1   5.483765    266.668732  268.837402  1   5.441666    272.687500  272.724976  100 0.000000    100 0.000000
-0.018000   -0.018000   1   5.478448    265.918732  267.837402  1   5.438361    270.687500  273.406219  100 0.000000    100 0.000000
.
.
.
.
89.932000   89.932000   1   5.604879    289.575165  273.574738  1   5.255306    301.056091  303.812744  3   0.000000    3   0.000000
89.964000   89.964000   1   5.650856    289.575165  269.574738  1   5.255306    301.056091  301.812744  3   0.000000    3   0.000000
<\MERGED-PUPIL-DATA>
.
.
.
<\SESSION>
```

Comment: I think it would be more like valid XML if the <\TAG>s were </TAG>s

Comment: If external tools are acceptable and you have a unix toolset I'd use `awk` to match the sections you want and cut them out to new files which R can read.

Comment: Can you post a link to the full dataset? I think one of your problems is the line `color code -> 100=unknown,`. The XML package doesn't like `<` or `>` in element text.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong-way slashes are going to thwart any attempt to use XML processing unless you first do a search and replace. The other approach is to read the file in as lines and search for tags.

Read the data file:

```
txt = readLines("dummy.txt")
```

Here's a function that returns text between matching tags, as a list in case there's more than one section:

```
getSection <- function(txt, tag){
    start=paste0("^<",tag,">$")
    end = paste0("^<\\\\",tag,">$") 
    startLines = grep(start,txt)
    endLines = grep(end,txt)
    lapply(1:length(startLines),function(i){
        txt[(startLines[i]+1):(endLines[i]-1)]
    })
}
```

So for example with a test file that has:

```
<DATE>
2014-01-20 14:29:43
<\DATE>
<DATE>
Never!
<\DATE>
```

I get:

```
> getSection(txt,"DATE")
[[1]]
[1] "2014-01-20 14:29:43"

[[2]]
[1] "Never!"
```

Suggest you write functions that wrap this for the various sections you want to parse, for example I've slightly edited your file to give this section a bit more regularity:

```
<STIMULUS-DEFINED>
redOS300
Default Human Relative Spectral Sensitivity
1   10.000000   20.000000   60.000000   1   
3   2.000000    -100.000000 0.000000    0.000000 
<\STIMULUS-DEFINED>
```

and then written:

```
getStimulusDefined <- function(lines){
    section = getSection(lines,"STIMULUS-DEFINED")[[1]] # only one of these
    data = read.table(textConnection(section),skip=1,head=TRUE)
    data
}
```

So I can then do:

```
> getStimulusDefined(txt)
  Default Human Relative Spectral Sensitivity
1       1    10       20       60           1
2       3     2     -100        0           0
```

and I get a data frame back (you'll need to rewrite this based on your understanding of that section).

It'll do odd things if tags are nested, but I doubt this file format will have that.

Is it fast enough/efficient enough? We won't know until you try it on your data, but it is at least a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  You methods proved quite efficient. I had assumed (wrongly!) that any method involving readLines would be too slow.

There is a slight error in your function though as it uses the arguments "lines" and "tag" in the definition, but "txt" and "tag" in the statements.  I assume "lines" should be "txt" in both places.

Comment: Yes, of course when I was developing this I had read the text into `txt` and that was matching inside the function instead of the names `lines` argument. Edited. Good spot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I´m making a complete mess here, but I am new to Stackoverflow. I wanted to expand a bit on Spacedman's excellent answer but couldn't get my code in a commment.

I've altered Spacedman's function to make a more generic function to read data frames.

The startSkip and endSkip arguments can be used to ignore lines at the start and end of each block.

I seems to work pretty fast on my files at least.

```
getSection <- function(file, tag,startSkip=0,endSkip=0){
  txt<-readLines(file)
  start=paste0("^<",tag,">$")
  end = paste0("^<\\\\",tag,">$") 
  startLines = grep(start,txt)
  endLines = grep(end,txt)
  noLines=endLines-startLines-startSkip-endSkip-1
  read.table(file,skip=startLines+startSkip,nrows=noLines)  
}
```

Comment: I separated the reading of the file from the extracting of the parts because then you don't need to read the whole file in every time to extract each tagged part.

Comment: That's a good point.  Although it seems to run pretty fast even if I read the file each time, it would be better to avoid that.
I just don't quite know how to read a data frame without using read.table() and the whole file

Comment: Sorry, I see you already have a solution for that.  I guess I should have read your answer better!